# How see the Output of stored Procedure in TOAD

Tags: stored-procedures, toad

I am new in using `TOAD`

There is one stored procedure having some input parameters and an out parameter.

I am executing the stored procedure by `Right click -> Execute Procedure`

Doing this will open a new window 'Set Parameter' where I enter the input parameter values and click OK. This displays the message `'Procedure completed.'`

Now, my question is, even if procedure is executed successfully, I am not able to see the output (as we see the output of simple oracle query).

What should I do to see the Output of stored Procedure? **(I am new to TOAD)**

Comment: For Oracle you usually need: `set serveroutput on`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Do u mean I need to execute set `serveroutput on ` with my stored procedure ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

serveroutput on is for script execution only and won't help you here. Since you're executing from the Schema Browser you'll need to open the View|DBMS Output window and enable output (the leftmost button should be down and green). You can also set it up to poll every X secs or you can leave polling off and poll manually afterwards. Now, execute your procedure and you'll see the output of any dbms_output.put_line statements that you have within. If your procedure returns values through OUT parameters then you can add dbms_output.put_line statements in the Set Parameters window to the anonymous block at the bottom after the execute procedure line. If you execute from the Editor you can manage the DBMS Output from the DBMS Output panel at the bottom without needing to open the full blown DBMS Output window.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to edit the anon block. In the Set Parameters window there's an "Output Options" tab. From there you can output OUT params and REF CURSOR results. You will need to enable DBMS Output as described in my answer to see it though.